# HTTP_USER_AGENT Location Internet Explorer 10

Tags: php, internet-explorer, redirect, internet-explorer-10

I am looking for a correct code passage because mine does not work on IE 10. I searched stackoverflow, and spent many hours on the internet, but the issues are not the same (and the tips on MSDN had errors on all the code examples!)

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (strpos($ua,'MSIE') != false && strpos($ua,'Opera') === false) {
    if (strpos($ua,'Windows NT 5.2') != false) {
        if(strpos($ua,'.NET CLR') === false) return;
        }
        if (substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1) < 7){
            header('Location: http://www.domain.org/xxxx/browser.html');
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

This code works for all IE versions except IE 10! IE 10 hangs, shows a blank pages with the url of the redirecting page browser.html.

With IE6 and IE 7 you see the browser.html with the message that you should upgrade your IE version.

What is wrong with this code?? I know that I could use conditional comments but redirecting would be better for my case.

Comment: Start by explaining what you want to do. Where do you change the response status to 301 or 302? You know that IE10 will never run on Windows NT5.2, right? You know that IE10 will not send a .NET CLR token except in CompatView mode, right?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Internet Explorer 10 does not sending *.NET CLR* information in user-agent string any more. First try to remove this:

```
if(strpos($ua,'.NET CLR') === false) return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have the solution! It has nothing to do with the code passage:

```
if (strpos($ua,'Windows NT 5.2') != false)
```

or

```
if(strpos($ua,'.NET CLR') === false) return;
```

The problem is on line

```
 if (substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1) < 7){
```

Internet Explorer 10 does not understand the math sign < .

If I write it like this:

```
if ((substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1) == 6) || (substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1) == 7))
```

the code works!

So here is the whole code which works on IE6 and IE7 (it redirects to the page browser.html) and with IE8, IE9 AND IE10 (and all the other not ie browsers):

```
<?php
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (strpos($ua,'MSIE') != false && strpos($ua,'Opera') === false){
    if ((substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1) == 6) || (substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1) == 7)) 
    {
        header('Location: http://www.domain.org/xxxx/browser.html');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

So, you can insert the first two lines I mentioned above. It works also with these two lines, but I thought: the less code I use, the more better :-)

Maybe other people will test it too. On my virtual windows 7 the problems are solved now.

Answer (score 0):

These are two examples of IE user agent:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; [platform token] Trident/6.0; Touch)
```

As you can see, the problem comes in when trying to detect IE version at the line:

```
if (substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1) < 7){
```

because in the case of version `10.0`, `substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1)` will match only `1` and not `10`, so `1 < 7`.

An easy way to fix it can be this:

```
preg_match('#MSIE ([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{0,2});#si',$ua,$m);
if ($m[1] < 7) {
  [your code]
}
```